# While read from file with sequence number

Tags: shell, for

I want to write a file using echo command. The echo commend will get data from anther file.

Here is the echo command:

```
echo '{
       name: $name
       id: $seq
       }
```

I have a txt file:

```
customer 1
customer 2
customer 3
```

So I want to generate a file doing echo and replace $name from fist line from the txt file.

And then replace $seq start with 1.

This is the file i want.

```
{
       name: customer 1
       id: 1
       }
{
       name: customer 2
       id: 2
       }
{
       name: customer 3
       id: 3
       }
```

While reading first line, the ID should be 1, while reading second line the ID should be 2`

Comment: show where do `$name` and `$seq` come from? Your current `echo` approach is not optimal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
 awk '{printf "{\n\tname: %s\n\tid: %d\n\t}\n",$0,NR}' file.txt
```

where

- `printf` will skip line, add tab and format string.

for `id:` argument, you can either use second field in your sample file, or generate one from line number (that is `NR` (Number of Record) value).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a proper JSON formatted output:

```
jq -Rs 'split("\n") |
        .[0:-1]     |
        [ foreach .[] as $customer ( 0; .+1; { name: $customer, id: . } ) ]' ./file
```

or, shorter,

```
$ jq -Rs '[ foreach split("\n")[0:-1][] as $customer ( 0; .+1; { name: $customer, id: . } ) ]' ./file
```

With `-Rs` we read unformatted raw text as single string of characters. This is split on newlines into an array with `split("\n")` and since we get an empty value at the end of the array we remove it with `.[0:-1]` (this selects all elements from the first to the second to last).

With the same input data as in the question, we now have

```
[
  "customer 1",
  "customer 2",
  "customer 3"
]
```

We then iterate over the values of this array with each element in `$customer` and the iterator in `.` and construct an array of objects with `name` and `id` keys accordingly.

The result is

```
[
  {
    "name": "customer 1",
    "id": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "customer 2",
    "id": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "customer 3",
    "id": 3
  }
]
```